# Getting null value from postgresql table

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-mvc, locking

I am working on a Spring MVC project. I am having issue with getting null values from database after some time interval. Following is the method written in DAO which return last entered value.

```
@Override
public String getDashboardData() {
    String q = "SELECT deviceid FROM main_tbl order by id DESC limit 1";
    String newId = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(q, String.class);
    System.out.println(newId);
    return newId;
}
```

This method is called from jsp with every 1 sec. My problem is that, this method returns bunch of some values & null value alternately. I didn't get the actual reason because everything works fine.

My output is like below:

```
01
05
09
41
null
null
null
null
15
09
05
65
10
null
null
null
null
```

Is that problem with postgresql..? Or is their any that I missed.
I’ll be very grateful for any help!

Comment: what sees a problem to you?.. `deviceid ` column is `NOT NULL`?..

Comment: No. The value I get from query `SELECT deviceid FROM main_tbl order by id DESC limit 1` is `null`. The table contains thousands of data then it is not possible to get null value. but It shows `real value & null value` alternatively with buch.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why "thousands of data" can't be real value & null value?..

Comment: Please read my question again. i have showed console output their.

Comment: do you receive the same number of right/wrong values? for instance 4 good deviceid and then 4 null's and so on

Comment: are you sure deviceId its also String type and not numeric?

Comment: `@cralfaro. ` Yes I received right values i.e. some right deviceid and some are null's that may be 4, 5 or 10 times.

Comment: `Problem is solved.` I was getting null values because I was forgot to close the connection. Due to that, with every time fetching the values from database it creates new connection. and my postgresql has the 100 connection limit.